# Filtering with jQuery Isotope leads to jerky animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-isotope

I'm using [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) on a project, but have run into an issue when using the filter method.

Filtering the list hides the undesired elements fine, but the transitioning animations aren't as smooth as the demos have me believe they should be.

The following code should illustrate my point; the filters apply and the elements do animate, but there are noticeable, visual jumps:

```js
var config = {
    itemSelector: '.grid_item',
    percentPosition: true,
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    fitRows: {
        gutter: '.grid_gutter'
    }
}

$('.grid').isotope(config);

$('.filter').on('click', function(){
    var type = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.grid').isotope({
        filter : '.' + type
    });
});

$('#clear').on('click', function(){
    $('.grid').isotope({
        filter : '*'
    });
});
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.grid {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 0;
}

.grid_item {
    background: gray;
    margin: 0 0 1%;
    padding-top: 40%;
    position: relative;
    width: 49.5%;
}

.grid_text {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.grid_gutter {
    width: 1%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/2.2.1/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>

<button class="filter" id="exit">Exit</button>
<button class="filter" id="creation">Creation</button>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>

<ul class="grid">
    <div class="grid_gutter"></div>
    <li class="grid_item exit">
        <span class="grid_text">Exit</span>
    </li>
    <li class="grid_item creation">
        <span class="grid_text">Creation</span>
    </li>
    <li class="grid_item creation">
        <span class="grid_text">Creation</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I assume that it's something in my CSS that's causing the issue, but I can't weed it out.

Also, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/verism/evzapk7k/3/).

Comment: Hi, this example is a bit different than yours, but it may be useful https://jsfiddle.net/tovly/w0avjdx9/

Comment: A down-vote, more than a day after I posted this and no comment as to why? Seriously? How does a question with functioning code snippet, jsfiddle link, and a genuine problem, warrant being down-voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is a problem with Isotope or if we were both doing the same wrong thing, but I had the same issue and resolved it by not using percentPosition at all. The [Isotope documentation](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout.html#responsive-layouts) says using percentPosition "reduce[s] adjustment transitions on window resize", so I guess not using it may cause performance problems.

Comment: Weird... all of their examples (that I can recall) also have it included, but you're right; removing that argument does get rid of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

For me the issue was that I had a transition applied to the elements which was causing it to be jerky. Setting the transition to 0s fixed it for me.